# Must ID attributes be unique in XML?

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, xml-attribute

Having an XML document like this:

```
<Fathers>
  <Father ID="1">
    <Name>Homer</Name>
    <Sons>
       <Son ID="1">
           <Name>Bart</Name>
       </Son>
    </Sons>
  </Father>
</Fathers>
```

Is it valid to have the same attribute name `ID` in different nested tags?

Also, is it valid to have duplicate `ID` values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ID attribute *values* must be unique in an XML document:

> **[Validity constraint: ID](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#id)**
>
> Values of type **ID** must match the [Name](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-Name) production. A name must
> not appear more than once in an XML document as a value of this type;
> i.e., ID values must uniquely identify the elements which bear them.

Regarding your other question, yes, it is ok to have the same attribute *names*, even `ID`, among nested elements.